# How can I fire event when I select to an especific jquery-UI tabs?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I´m trying to fire event when I select an especific tab, not any selected tab.
for example, I have 3 tabs and I want to the diferents things if I select tabs-1,tabs-2 or tabs-3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".Tabs").tabs();
    jQuery(".Tabs").tabs("disable",1);
    jQuery(".Tabs").tabs("disable",2);
    jQuery(".Tabs").tabs("disable",3);
    jQuery('.Tabs').bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {    
        ui.tab 
        ui.panel
        ui.index
        if (ui.index==0) {
        }else if (ui.index==3) {
            loadFirstTabData();
         }else if (ui.index==3) {
            loadSecondTabData();
        } 
});
```

this is how it works.
.Tabs is class attribute of tabs `<li class='Tabs'>`
**Note** : this is a working code

Comment: thanks you it works perfectly. I only change disable options and ui.index (not alwways 3).